# How to dynamically route RxJS streams

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I have a stream of data from car auctions.  Each car auction has n-number of lanes.  I want to log the auction of each vehicle.

The stream looks something like this...

--{lane: 1, action: bid} --- { lane: 2, action: start} --- { lane:1, action: bid} --- {lane: 2, action: bid} --- {lane:1, action: sold} ---

I have the following to buffer each auction lane and close the buffer on sale...

```
const bufferOpen$= auctionWebSocketStream$
    .filter(stream => stream.tag === 'CURITEM');

const bufferClose$ = () => auctionWebSocketStream$.filter(stream => stream.tag === 'SOLD');

auctionWebSocketStream$
  .bufferToggle(bufferOpen$, bufferClose$)
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

The above works fine so long as there is one auction and one lane.  With multiple lanes, there's bid/sale information about multiple lanes.

How would I aggregate the stream by lanes into the buffer?  Similar solutions always had known aggregation parameters.  But I need to split the stream anytime there's a new lane.

Help is greatly appreciated.

## UPDATE

I made a JSBin to show off my frustration and cluelessness.  It gives an example input stream and explains the desired output.

http://jsbin.com/tuxitev/edit?js,console

(For bonus points, it only shows empty arrays under Babel.  Not sure why Typescript is required)

Comment: Just stumbled on groupBy... I think I'm about to have a "sorry for wasting everyone's time" moment.

Comment: Do you have a fixed number of lanes? Can a land reopen for a new auction?

Comment: It's not fixed and it could reopen.  E.g. Auction 1, lanes A, B, C --- Auction 2, lanes A, B --- Auction 1, lane D --- Auction 1, lane A complete --- Auction 3, lane A

Comment: So when it reopen, do you subscribe again?

Comment: Yes, it would need to resubscribe.  This is a bit of an edge case, and if it's causing a lot of problems, I can take the non-resubscribed version.

Comment: Or keep the subscription live. If there's no new data, it wouldn't make a difference, and if a new auction starts, it can process it as before

Comment: Good point.  The program will terminate at night anyway, so any memory issues aren't terribly relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If someone knows where to get RxJS questions answered, please let me know.  I'll accept the answer.  This is the third unanswered RxJS question I've had.

For anyone curious of the answer, here it is.

```
stream$
.groupBy(stream => stream.lane)
.mergeMap(stream =>
        stream.scan((acc, cur) => {
                if (cur.action === 'start') {
                    acc = [];
                }
                acc.push(cur)
                return acc;
        }, [])
        .filter(stream => stream[stream.length-1].action === 'sold')
)
.subscribe(
    x => console.log(x), 
    (e) => console.error(e), 
    () => console.log('complete')
)
```

http://jsbin.com/tuxitev/edit?js,console